# Copy (duplicate) a file in the OneDrive app

Tags: onedrive

I have a PDF I want to duplicate into another folder on the OneDrive app. However, the only way I've been able to make it work is by saving the document, editing it, and then re-uploading onto OneDrive. I want to use OneDrive's built-in PDF editing tool but this just throws a spanner in the works.

I cannot find an option to copy/duplicate a file within the OneDrive app on Android.

Is there a way to copy/duplicate a file in the OneDrive app?

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot add a comment being a starter to this forum, I would like say that I am not sure how to do it other ways, but I am good at Rest API and have done it through this earlier. Let me give you a code for that if you are interested, else give me a comment and I would delete the answer.

> COPY
>   https://apis.live.net/v5.0/file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!126
>
> Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
>   Content-Type: application/json
>
> {
>       "destination": "folder.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!114" }

Also, as you rightly said, there are forums like forums.dev.windows.com where you can ask such questions.

Answer (score -1):

If you really like the OneDrive app, good. But i use [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en), it has many options. To get OneDrive in ES File Explorer, you go into Network, then add, and you can add your google drive, OneDrive, etc. Then it's simple to add, hide, encrypt, copy, and do whatever else to folders and files. All within the file explorer. I tried to edit a pdf with my version with the built in text editor, but it didn't work. If you want to edit pdf's you could get a pdf editor.